# Automatic Ordering of Object Files "*.o" in a Fortran Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies, fortran, wildcard

Here I have two Fortran90 files and a makefile:

*Contents of file* **main_mod.f90**:

```
module main_mod

contains

  subroutine add(a, b)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: a, b
    print *, (a+b)
  end subroutine add

end module main_mod
```

*contents of file* **main_mod2.f90**

```
module main_mod2
  use main_mod

contains

  subroutine add2(a, b)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: a, b

    call add(a, b)
  end subroutine add2

end module main_mod2
```

and in **makefile**, I automatically generate a list of ".o" files from current directory:

```
F90 = /usr/bin/gfortran
COMPFLAGS    =  -c
%.o: %.f90
        $(F90) $(COMPFLAGS) $*.f90

all: $(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(wildcard *.f90))
```

when I make the project, the wildcard statement in my make file generates a list of object files like:

```
main_mod2.o main_mod.o
```

and then the compilation fails because first, the file *main_mod.f90* needs be compiled which would give us *main_mod.o* and *main_mod.mod* used in *main_mod2.f90*. Then *main_mod2.f90* would be compiled successfully. That means the permutation of object files must be:

```
main_mod.o main_mod2.o
```

Now, the question is, in general case when I create the list of object files using wildcard, how can I enforce correct permutation of object files?

Comment: In this case, code in `main_mod2` uses code in `main_mod`. In the general case, *how in hell can Make guess which code uses which?*

Comment: @Beta "how in hell can Make guess which code uses which?" - you are right!!! But please take a look at an outstanding answer by Yossarian  to do such thing!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While gcc does have `-M` and related flags for doing exactly this with C/C++ files, they unfortunately do not work with gfortran. Actually, it is possible, but only if you already know the dependencies. 
Therefore you will need an external program to generate your dependencies.

In my projects, I use [this python script](https://github.com/ZedThree/fort_depend.py), and add the following to my makefile:

```
# Script to generate the dependencies
MAKEDEPEND=/path/to/fort_depend.py

# $(DEP_FILE) is a .dep file generated by fort_depend.py
DEP_FILE = my_project.dep

# Source files to compile
OBJECTS = mod_file1.f90 \
          mod_file2.f90

# Make sure everything depends on the .dep file
all: $(actual_executable) $(DEP_FILE)

# Make dependencies
.PHONY: depend
depend: $(DEP_FILE)

# The .dep file depends on the source files, so it automatically gets updated
# when you change your source
$(DEP_FILE): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Making dependencies!"
    cd $(SRCPATH) && $(MAKEDEPEND) -w -o /path/to/$(DEP_FILE) -f $(OBJECTS)

include $(DEP_FILE)
```

`fort_depend.py` basically just makes a list of all the modules `USE`d in a given file.

Comment: Thank you for this incredible answer! The only problem I have now is that the python script always gives me the following error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "fort_depend.py", line 161, in <module> for arg in args.D: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Have you had similar error before? How can I fix it? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I think I've just fixed that bug. Can you try again with the latest changes?

Comment: `fort_depend.py` allows you to specify preprocessor macros, for my probably incredibly specific use-case. I've not found another Fortran dependency generator which allows you do that.

Comment: I run "./fort_depend.py -f mod_file1.f90 mod_file2.f90" to parse files to python script. However, there is something wrong when it looks up in the dictionary. Here is the error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fort_depend.py", line 172, in <module>
    run(files=args.files, verbose=args.verbose, overwrite=args.overwrite, macros=macros, output=output)
  File "./fort_depend.py", line 9, in run
    mod2fil=file_objs_to_mod_dict(FIL_OBJS=l)
TypeError: file_objs_to_mod_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'FIL_OBJS'. I would be glad if you fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that was me being very sloppy, it's now fixed.

Comment: Also, if you feel this solved your problem, you can click accept (and upvote if you like) :)

Comment: Works Now!! Great work Yossarian! I guess this script should be general enough to work for large number of source files because you do a brute-force search and ordering. I wish I could give 1000+ points to this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

... Specify them in your rules.

```
main_mod2.o: main_mod.o
```

Comment: If you noticed, in my question, I asked "when the list of object files are generated by using wildcards how I can specify the permutation?". I don't want to manually specify rule for each single file and this is the reason that I ask this question. What if I had 2000 files in my project? Do you think manual approach would work efficiently?

Comment: You need to specify them *somewhere*. The rules are simply the most obvious solution.

Comment: I suspect that there should be some built in facility in GNU make that tells the maker program to first detect and compile the most independent source files (call them layer1) and then compile layer2 which depends on layer1 and then layer3 .. and so on. It might be a keyword or flag or a hint to maker. I am trying to find it if it exists :))

Comment: I believe that gcc has something for that, but I'm not sure if it extends to gfortran.

Comment: I can write a lua or python script for that for my particular purpose, but before that I want to make sure that there is really no hope with gfortran makefile structure.

Comment: And how would make guess what these "layer1", "layer2", etc. sections should contain?  Make doesn't contain a FORTRAN parser.  It doesn't know what the relationship between your source files is.  If you're willing to separate out your sources into these layers yourself you can tell make that the files in layer2 all depend on all the output from layer1; that's not hard.  Otherwise you'll have to use your tools that DO understand FORTRAN syntax (e.g., gfortran) to automatically generate those dependencies.

Comment: @MadScientist It is possible to detect layer1 and layer2 etc using a python or lua script as I mentioned before. This might not be fast and scalable like native GCC parser but it works! Please take a look at the recent answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that's basically what I suggested in the last sentence of my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it in my makefile. You shouldn't reference fortdepends.py but the binary file. You can locate this using find -name fortdepends

Here's my make file. Link to my github https://github.com/pjuangph/fortran

```
# Makefile with autodependancy generation
# Note: Before running, you need to install fortdepend `pip install fortdepend` 
#       fortdepend path can vary so make sure you edit the MAKEDEPEND variable

## Compiler Flags
FC=gfortran     # Fortran Compiler
FFLAGS= -g -Wall -Wextra # -O2  # Note: Compiler optimization flags like -O2 will interfere with debugging
LINKER = $(FC) -o
FCLINKS = -g 
#FFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -fopenmp      # OpenMP

# $(DEP_FILE) is a .dep file generated by fort_depend.py
DEP_FILE = my_project.dep
PROG = main.exe

# Source files to compile
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name '*.f95')
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.f95=.o)

## Auto Generation of Dependancies 
MAKEDEPEND=~/anaconda3/envs/dev/bin/fortdepend
depend:=$(shell $(MAKEDEPEND) -f $(SOURCES) -o $(DEP_FILE))

include $(DEP_FILE)

# Make all Targets
all: $(PROG)

%.o : %.f95
    @echo "-----------------------------"
    @echo "Compiling the files into objects"
    @echo "-----------------------------"
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

$(PROG) : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "-----------------------------"
    @echo "Creating the executable"
    @echo "-----------------------------"
    $(LINKER) $(PROG) $(OBJECTS) $(FCLINKS)

clean:
    rm -r *.mod *.o *.exe *.dep
```