# FORTRAN Makefile for a large project

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, fortran, gnu-make, linker-errors

I am starting a new project in Fortran95 that should become big quickly (a lot of modules). At the moment I have only

- output.f90
- moldyn.f90

output.f90 contains a module with a few public variables, two public subroutines and two private subroutines. moldyn.f90 contains the main program calling the two public subroutines contained in output.f90.

It is the first time that I tackle a large project, therefore I would like to automate as much as possible compilation and linking by creating a general and easily adaptable Makefile. Makefiles I created before were only "hard-coded" compilation and linking statements and for a large project I would like to automate the process (but without using other tools as CMake).

This is my attempt that unfortunately does not work:

```
# ========
# Makefile
# ========

# Makefile name
MF = Makefile

# ==========
# Executable
# ==========

# Executable name
EXE = $(BINDIR)/moldyn.x

# ========
# Compiler
# ========

# Fortran compiler
FC = gfortran

# Fortran flags
FFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Warray-bounds -fbounds-check

# ===========
# Directories
# ===========
SRCDIR = src
BINDIR = bin
OBJDIR = obj
MODDIR = mod

# ========
# Suffixes
# ========

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .f90 .o .mod

# ===================
# Sources and objects
# ===================

SRC = \
    $(SRCDIR)/moldyn.f90\
    $(SRCDIR)/output.f90

OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)%.f90=$(OBJDIR)%.o)

# =====
# Rules
# =====

all:
    @echo $(SRC)
    @echo $(OBJ)

moldyn: $(OBJDIR)/.o $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $(SRCDIR)/$@ $(OBJ)

$(OBJDIR)/.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $(SRC)

$(OBJ): $(MF)

# =======
# Folders
# =======

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(MODDIR):
    mkdir -p $(MODDIR)

# =====
# Clean
# =====

clean:
    rm -f src/*~
    rm -fr $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR) $(MODDIR)
```

I think that the mess comes from the fact that I have the sources in a src/ folder and I want to create the .o in an obj/ folder and the executable in bin/ folder. .mod files also play a role since they are created in the dase folder (where there is the makefile), but I don't really know how to deal with them (it is my first Fortran project).

Can anyone help me to understand where compilations problems come from? The error I get is the following:

```
gfortran -O2 -Wall -Warray-bounds -fbounds-check -c src/moldyn.f90 

src/output.f90
src/moldyn.f90:20.6:

  use output, only: title, gpl
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'output.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/.o] Error 1
```

and seems to be related with the .mod files.

Comment: Look in your directories and see where the files have been put. How does the compile step put the *.o files in $(OBJDIR). It may be the *.o files are in the $(SRC) directory, not the $(OBJDIR).

Comment: @KeithSmith With `make all` I tested the path and the command `OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)%.f90=$(OBJDIR)%.o)` works as expected, i.e. the values in OBJ all start with $(OBJDIR)/. However the *.o and *.mod are created in the current directory.

Comment: Handmade Makefile is a nightmare. CMake is a good choice for large projects. I use SCons instead, because I didn't want to learn yet another language and SCons is just Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think your makefile questions are all pretty much answered in this Stack Overflow post:
[Automatic Ordering of Obejct Files "*.o" in a Fortran Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705273/automatic-ordering-of-obejct-files-o-in-a-fortran-makefile).

As far as your specific error, you need to include a `-I $(OBJDIR)` in your gfortran calls to tell it where your *.mod files are.

```
gfortran -O2 -Wall -Warray-bounds -fbounds-check -I obj/ -c src/moldyn.f90
```

Do reconsider CMake, though. We have a very large Fortran/C/C++ codebase (~800,000 lines of Fortran/~900,000 lines of C/C++) and have been pretty happy with CMake. For us, we need to build/test/deploy on Windows/Mac/Linux and CMake does that for us. We also use GNU and Intel compilers and it handles that. We also have debug and release builds and coverage testing and memory leak builds. It also provides a testing harness with CTest and a continuous integration dashboard with CDash. It is something that you can move to once your project gets bigger. So while your project is small, use the Makefile approach. If you start to feel the limitations, then don't put a lot of time into some elaborate Makefile generation scheme--I've been down that road. Just switch to CMake--here's a bonus link to an [example of CMake for Fortran](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample). And while I'm giving unsolicited advice, don't do "in source" builds. The reasons are summarized pretty well on [this blog post by Jussi Pakkanen](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/04/16/why-you-should-consider-using-separate-build-directories/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`VPATH = <path>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) to tell `make` where to find the source files. You will need a compiler flag to change where the `.mod` files get built. For `gfortran` the flag is `-J<path>`.

To specify where the `.o` files get built, you can do something like this:

```
# Current directory
BASEPATH = $(shell pwd)

# Absolute paths to the directories
SRCDIR = $(BASEPATH)/src
BINDIR = $(BASEPATH)/bin
OBJDIR = $(BASEPATH)/obj
MODDIR = $(BASEPATH)/mod

# Put module files in their own directory
FFLAGS += -J$(MODDIR)

# Search path for source code
VPATH = $(SRCDIR)

...

# Using VPATH, so no need to give full path to source
SRC = \
    moldyn.f90\
    output.f90

# Replace .f90 with .o
OBJ_O = $(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(SRC)
# Prepend object path
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJPATH)/,$(OBJ_O))

...

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f90
    # Check object and binary directories exist, make them if necessary
    # We can use the $(@D) magic variable to get the directory
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    # $@ means the left-hand side of the recipe
    # $< means all of the right hand side
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

As redwizard792 suggested, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25802895/2043465) to automatically generate the dependencies for the `.o` files. If you do so, you will need to include the additions to your makefile from that answer as well.