# Makefile produces for Fortran 90 causes unresolved external symbol

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90

My program is an mpi program which uses intel MKL. for simple, let us assume there are `main.f90 a.f90 b.f90` in which `a.f90` contains module called `mymod` needed by others

Usually I will compile it like this

```
mpiifort *90 /fast /Qmkl /MD -o main.exe
```

I just do it twice, because for the first time, there will be lack of `mymod.mod`

Now I want to use makefile, since I want to reduce recompiling time. I write it like this

```
IFORT = /fast
MKL =/Qmkl
LDFLAGS = /MD
main:main.obj b.obj
    mpiifort $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
mymod.mod:a.f90
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
main.obj:main.f90
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
b.obj:b.f90
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
```

However, there must be something wrong here. I got bunch of `unresolved external symbol`. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm not a makefile expert but it looks like your `main` target doesn't have any explicit dependence on `mymod.mod` so this won't get built. I could also be completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

Firstly somebody else can probably write a better/more complete answer (or direct us to one) and I would welcome this, but below I provide a very simple example.

Now we can identify the (probable) source of the errors :  If we replace the compilation command with just `touch` we can produce a simple example that demonstrates the issue

```
main:main.obj b.obj
        touch $@
mymod.mod:a.f90
        touch $@
main.obj:main.f90
        touch $@
b.obj:b.f90
        touch $@
```

If we then construct our "source files" with

```
>touch main.f90 b.f90 a.f90
```

we can then try to build our `main` executable:

```
>make main
```

which will output:

```
touch main.obj 
touch b.obj
touch main
```

Note how this does not create the `mymod.mod` file. This means that in your case `a.f90` does not get compiled when you build `main` and hence the required symobols are not available (i.e. when linking there are functions/routines etc. that are undefined as `a.obj` is not available). If we now show that `main` depends on `mymod.mod` by adjusting our makefile to be

```
main:main.obj b.obj mymod.mod
        touch $@
mymod.mod:a.f90
        touch $@
main.obj:main.f90
        touch $@
b.obj:b.f90
        touch $@
```

we can now try building `main` (after first cleaning up by doing `rm *.obj mymod.mod main`) and we get:

```
>make main
touch main.obj 
touch b.obj
touch mymod.mod 
touch main
```

So we have successfully got `make` to build the `mymod.mod` target as a part of building `main`. Note that in reality you probably want to ensure that some targets get built before others (e.g. here you probably want to compile `a.f90` before `b.f90`). You can do that with dependency lists, which you may wish to auto-generate (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25705273)).

Comment: Thank you very much d_1999. I figure out a way which is simpler : )

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way that is kind of automatic if we use intel fortran

Intel fortran provides an option called `gen-dep`, it will automatically analysis and output dependency information can be used for makefile. So just running the following command, **if there is error message due to missing mod file, just run it twice**

```
mpiifort *90 /Qmkl /gen-dep > dependency.txt
```

we got `dependency.txt`. Open it, we will find something like this

```
mpifc.bat for the Intel(R) MPI Library 5.1.2 for Windows*
Copyright(C) 2007-2015, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.

mymod.mod : \
  a.f90

a.obj : \
  a.f90

b.obj : \
  b.f90 mymod.mod

main.obj : \
  main.f90 \
  c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mpi\intel64\bin\..\..\intel64\include\mpi_base.mod \
  c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mpi\intel64\bin\..\..\intel64\include\mpi_sizeofs.mod \
  c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mpi\intel64\bin\..\..\intel64\include\mpi_constants.mod \
  c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mpi\intel64\bin\..\..\intel64\include\mpi.mod \
  mymod.mod

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:a.exe 
-subsystem:console 
"-libpath:c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win" 
"/LIBPATH:c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mpi\intel64\bin\..\..\intel64\lib\release_mt" 
"/LIBPATH:c:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146\windows\mpi\intel64\bin\..\..\intel64\lib" 
impi.lib 
a.obj 
b.obj 
main.obj
```

Those module related to mpi are static so just remove it. After some simple text manipulation(using regex would be a good choice) to make it more clear and compact, we can get a correct makefile like this(I have fixed some errors in my question post)

```
IFORT = /fast
MKL =/Qmkl
LDFLAGS = /MD
a: a.obj b.obj main.obj 
    mpiifort $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@.exe
mymod.mod : a.f90
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
a.obj : a.f90
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
b.obj : b.f90 mymod.mod
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
main.obj : main.f90 mymod.mod
    mpiifort /c $(IFORT) $(MKL) $(LDFLAGS) $<
```

Comment: Still it makes introducing a new file to the project a big pain. That's why I don't use `make` for Fortran any more. There much better automatic build tools available, `cmake`, `scons` and `waf`.

Comment: @VladimirF Hi, VladimirF. Years ago I thought makefile is just unnecessary. Months ago I began to use makefile, because it is handy to customize different working mode: build, clean, etc. Days ago, I am tired of recompiling because I am intensely tracing a bug, I must write a better makefile which specifiesdependencies. Maybe in the near future, I will be completely tired of makefile just like you : ) But by the way, would you like to add a simple illustration on cmake or others tools for fortran to compare traditional method? I searched on this site and didn't find any good answers on issue.

Comment: It would be off-topic to put anything here. There are many questions about cmake here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cmake%2Bfortran and for scons find something on github https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/SConstruct (this one is mine). There is a Documentation site for cmake as well http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cmake/topics

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you very much, especially the github page : )