# How to have make scan through different directories to find and compile modules before linking Fortran executable

Tags: makefile, module, fortran, gfortran

This is a follow up on questions [231229](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231229), [8855896](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855896) and [35234003](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35234003): I have a number of utility modules in *~/Fortran/include* and I am developing new code in *~/Fortran/ProjectA*. My dream *Makefile* would see that *A.f90* needs *mod_MyMod*, and check in *~/Fortran/include* to see if *mod_mymod.mod* and *mod_MyMod.o* exist, if not it would generate and place them in *include*, and then, after linking objects from both *include* and *ProjectA* it would produce *A* in *ProjectA*

So far I have  this:

```
FC = gfortran
PROGRAMS = A
FCFLAGS = -I../include
LDFLAGS = -lm -L/usr/local/lib 
# flags forall (e.g. look for system .mod files, required in gfortran)
# "make" builds all
all: $(PROGRAMS)
# Using Fortran MODULES:

A.o: ../include/mod_MyMod.o
A: ../include/mod_MyMod.o

# Linking
%: %.o
    $(FC)  -o  $@  $^   $(LDFLAGS)

# Compiling (fortran)
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<


# Utility targets

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

in *ProjectA/* I have

```
Program A
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: R64 => real64,I32 => int32,&
       & input_unit,output_unit,error_unit
  use mod_MyMod
  implicit none

  ! global variables

  character(len=23) :: string="This is A speaking"

  call Print_This(string)
End Program A
```

in *include/* I have

```
Module mod_MyMod
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: R64 => real64,I32 => int32,&
       & input_unit,output_unit,error_unit
  implicit none
contains
  Subroutine Print_This(string)
    character(len=20),intent(in) :: string
    write(output_unit,"(*(g0,:,' '))")string
  End Subroutine Print_This
End Module mod_MyMod
```

In order to accomplish what I want, I think I need separate rules for compiling *A.f90* and *mod_MyMod.f90*. In the first case the object is pointed to the local directory, in the second the *.mod* and *.o* are to be put in *include*.