# Fortran Undefined Reference Error

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I've installed gfortran through the MinGW-get installer.
I'm facing issues when I call a subroutine in Fortran and try to compile.
I have written a small program Hello.F and a subroutine World.F such that program Hello.F calls Subroutine World.F

When I compile Hello.f using the command `gfortran Hello.F`
I see an error as below,

```
Undefined Reference to 'World_'

collect2.exe: error: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Below is Hello.F,

```
PROGRAM HELLO
CALL WORLD
STOP
END
```

Below is World.F

```
SUBROUTINE WORLD
print *, "Hello World!"
RETURN
END
```

Both programs Hello.F and World.F reside in the same folder and I `cd` to this folder before typing in the command `gfortran hello.f` to compile the program.

Comment: Please use [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: I suggest you to find some good textbook or tutorial from this century for your beginnings. You are programming in a 40 years old style which should be forgotten. Learn particularly about  Fortran 95, free form source and other more recent stuff (25 years old). Learn about line indentation and why you do not need all the `RETURN` and `STOP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read up a bit here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranUsage

Specifically, you need to tell the compiler about all your files, for instance like this:

`gfortran -o executable source1.f90 source2.f90`

Or in your case:

`gfortran -o helloworld Hello.F World.F`

Comment: Thanx so much, this one worked. but in my actual scenario I have 100s of subroutine files. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Great! The standard way of automatizing this is a Makefile. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871780/creating-a-fortran-makefile